# Show a dropdown of tags that have been placed into text

Tags: feature-request, tags

When you insert a tag into a question or answer like this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) no dropdown appears when you hover over it. Can you add such a dropdown?

Comment: what about [tag:tags] [tag:that-dont] [tag:exist]?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aijb4.png

Comment: could this  feature request be marked status-norepro, please?

Comment: Don't try to add the tag yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already exists, but only for tags on the same site and with at least one question that contain that tag.

So, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for you. :-)